# react-gesture-gallery getting image to full screen width

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using a library called react-gesture-gallery to create a slideshow for my project and it's working but the images are not able to get 100vw for some reason. I tried setting the background color to red to see if the component was becoming the full width of the screen and it is but for some reason, not the image. This is a sample code from codeSandbox

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Gallery, GalleryImage } from "react-gesture-gallery";
import "./styles.css";

function Example() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const images = [
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557958114-3d2440207108?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"
    },
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557939403-1760a0e47505?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1931&q=80"
    },
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558029062-a37889b87526?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80"
    },
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558088458-b65180740294?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1579&q=80"
    },
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558039719-79cb7b60d279?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ background: "black", width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <Gallery
        index={index}
        onRequestChange={i => {
          setIndex(i);
        }}>
        {images?images.map(img => (
          <GalleryImage objectFit="contain" key={img.src} src={img.src} />
        )):''}
      </Gallery>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Example />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

One component for the gallery and a second component for the galleryImage. galleryImage shows the images but I cannot figure out how to display them to the full width of the screen.

Comment: the way I understand this question is you want 100vw for each image, and you're not able to do it, maybe it is happening due to image URL parameters i.e. `&fit=crop&w=1931&q=80`. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I just looked at the read me for the library and it says the following: "By default, the gallery will attempt to fit into its container using `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`, so you should generally provide a container with a set width and height. For a full-screen gallery, using `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`. Note that this library doesn't display in a modal by default, but it's easy enough to provide your own."

Comment: The gallery itself fits fine as a child but the galleryImage doesn't display the image itself as the full width. it's a child of the gallery